# Issues with multi-module Maven project on Dockerfile

Tags: maven, kotlin, dockerfile

I have a project with the following structure:

```
+-- the_project
   +-- springapp1
   |   `-- pom.xml
   |   `-- Dockerfile
   +-- springapp2
   |   `-- pom.xml
   |   `-- Dockerfile
    `- pom.xml
```

Apart from that I have a docker-compose file in a separate folder, but I'll omit it's code, cause I think that the issue is not there.

Every Dockerfile looks like this (difference -- jar name):

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_BUILD
COPY ../pom.xml /build/
COPY ./pom.xml /build/child/
COPY src /build/child/src/
WORKDIR /build/child/
RUN mvn package

FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/app1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /app/
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=prod","-jar","/app1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"]
```

Main (root) POM here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.the_project</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>springapp1</module>
        <module>springapp2</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
--lot's of dependencies here--
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Spring application 1 POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.the_project</groupId>
        <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>springapp1</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <start-class>*I have a starter class here*</start-class>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.5.31</kotlin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>2.5.6</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>
                                        bla-bla-bla
                                    </mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>bla-bla-bla</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Omitted the POM for the second app, will provide if needed.
(I also had to replace some names with generic ones, really sorry for that, let's just assume I double-checked all the names of classes and artifacts, they are fine, issue's not there)

So, when I run docker compose up I have this error:

```
#22 1.731 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
#22 1.802 [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
#22 1.803 [WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' of POM org.the_project:springapp1:[unknown-version] (/build/child/pom.xml) points at org.the_project:apringapp1 instead of org.the_project:Project, please verify your project structure @ line 5, column 1
0
#22 1.803 [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.the_project:springapp1:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact org.the_project:Project:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10
#22 1.804  @
#22 1.805 [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
#22 1.806 [ERROR]
#22 1.806 [ERROR]   The project org.the_project:springapp1:[unknown-version] (/build/child/pom.xml) has 1 error
#22 1.806 [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.the_project:springapp1:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact org.the_project:Project:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10 ->
 [Help 2]
#22 1.807 [ERROR]
#22 1.807 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
#22 1.807 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
#22 1.808 [ERROR]
```

There was a question with the exact same error ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57366246/non-resolvable-parent-pom-on-docker-build)) but it does not seem there was a solution.

I already spent several hours trying to understand what's wrong and I just can't see any solution.

The problem is definitely here (because manual "clean package" /as well as other commands/ work more than fine):

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_BUILD
bla bla bla
```

It does not see the parent POM.
I have just NOOOO idea why!((

Any ideas are very welcome....

Comment: If you really like to build within a container you have to copy all directories `springapp1` and `springapp2`...plus `pom.xml`...

Comment: So every child (app 1 and app 2) in their dockerfiles should have smth like this?
`COPY ../pom.xml /build/
(new line)
COPY .  /build/child/
(new line)
WORKDIR /build/child/`

Comment: Nope, did not work :(  I copied parent POM as well as all the child files and still this error that he can't see my parent POM

Comment: Than you are doing something wrong... this looks strange because `../pom.xml` reference a pom file which is not in the given structure... The question is where your Dockerfile is located in the directory structure?

Comment: Each of the 2 Dockerfiles lies in the root spring application directory (in springapp1/2 folder), that's why (according to your suggestion) I copied a parent POM to build folder (../pom.xml to /build), copied everything from the current directory to build/child (dot to build/child). This is how I thought I'd save the hierarchy of folders in the container (child POM's parent: <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>). Basically app in container (in child folder) will see parent POM when going up (2 dots) in build folder. Am I wrong in smth?

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution in case anyone ever bumps into similar error.

In docker compose yaml I specified wrong context for each of my 2 applications. You should set it to your root project, otherwise docker won't see your "../pom.xml" (parent pom), basically, for docker there will be no such place as "..".

In my case I have my docker-compose.yaml in "docker" folder, which is located in root folder of the project. So I simply set context to "..".

```
  spring_app_1:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: ./springapp1/Dockerfile
```